# Is there any way to make this function look nicer?

Tags: python

I need a logic that will extract a url from Apache log file:
right now I did this:

```
apache_log = {'@source': 'file://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx//var/log/apache2/access.log', '@source_host': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', '@message': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx - - [02/Aug/2013:12:38:37 +0000] "POST /user/12345/product/2 HTTP/1.1" 404 513 "-" "PycURL/7.26.0"', '@tags': [], '@fields': {}, '@timestamp': '2013-08-02T12:38:38.181000Z', '@source_path': '//var/log/apache2/access.log', '@type': 'Apache-access'}
data = apache_log['@message'].split()
if data.index('"POST') and data[data.index('"POST')+2].startswith('HTTP'):
     print data[data.index('"POST')+1]
```

It returns me:

```
/user/12345/product/2
```

Basically the result is correct, but the way I did it I don't really like.

Can someone suggest better (more Pythonic) way of extracting this path from apache log file.

Comment: Belongs on codereview.SE.

Comment: I don't think the `if data.index('"POST')` part works the way you want. For future reference, checking whether something is in a list is just `'"POST' in data`.

Comment: that's right , I missed this part

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A regular expression would work better:

```
import re

post_path = re.compile(r'"POST (/\S+) HTTP')

match = post_path.search(apache_log['@message'])
if match:
    print match.group(1)
```

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> apache_log = {'@source': 'file://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx//var/log/apache2/access.log', '@source_host': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', '@message': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx - - [02/Aug/2013:12:38:37 +0000] "POST /user/12345/product/2 HTTP/1.1" 404 513 "-" "PycURL/7.26.0"', '@tags': [], '@fields': {}, '@timestamp': '2013-08-02T12:38:38.181000Z', '@source_path': '//var/log/apache2/access.log', '@type': 'Apache-access'}
>>> post_path = re.compile(r'"POST (/\S+) HTTP')
>>> match = post_path.search(apache_log['@message'])
>>> if match:
...     print match.group(1)
... 
/user/12345/product/2
```

Comment: Thank you @Martijn your answers are always great!